# QLineSeries::setUseOpenGL work incorrectly with specific data

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I work on Windows 10, ide - Qt Creator, compiler - Visual Studio 2017.

I am testing "LineChart Example"
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-linechart-example.html#

I change data in this one. I can see a good result.

If uncomment line

```
//series->setUseOpenGL(true); //don'n work!
```

a chart is not drawn.

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QtCharts/QChartView>
#include <QtCharts/QLineSeries>
#include <QtCharts/QValueAxis>

QT_CHARTS_USE_NAMESPACE

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    const int count = 1495;
    const double _xmin(17249.999500);
    const double _xmax(17250.000500);
    const double _ymin(4.0);
    const double _ymax(8.0);
    double _xstep((_xmax-_xmin)/count);
    double _ystep((_ymax-_ymin)/count);

    QValueAxis* _axisX = new QValueAxis;
    QValueAxis* _axisY = new QValueAxis;
    _axisX->setRange(_xmin, _xmax);
    _axisY->setRange(_ymin, _ymax);

    QLineSeries *series = new QLineSeries();

    for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
        series->append(_xmin + _xstep*i, _ymin + _ystep*i);
    }
    //series->setUseOpenGL(true); //don'n work!

    QChart *chart = new QChart();

    chart->legend()->hide();
    chart->addSeries(series);
    chart->createDefaultAxes();
    chart->setTitle("Simple line chart example");

    chart->setAxisX(_axisX, series);
    chart->setAxisY(_axisY, series);

    QChartView *chartView = new QChartView(chart);
    chartView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    QMainWindow window;
    window.setCentralWidget(chartView);
    window.resize(600, 400);
    window.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

I did some new experiments with data. In case  series->setUseOpenGL(true);

If I set

```
const double _xmin(17249.999500); //stairs
const double _xmax(17250.015500); //stairs
```

I can see the stairs instead of straight!

Comment: In linux with Qt 5.13 it works correctly, maybe it is a bug in Windows, report it.

Comment: Yes, maybe it is a bug in Windows. But Qt is a wrapper for a system. And I expect the wrapper to hide all the details of working with the system. In addition, with other data, this application works very well under Windows.    It’s very funny to display a chart with some data  -  const double _xmin(17249.999500);   const double _xmax(17250.015500);

Comment: It is obvious what you point out but Qt also have errors: bugs, and especially the Qt Charts sub-module they have not given much love for what is common to find such errors, I remember that in an old question I had the same problem in Linux but It seems that in the most recent versions it has been solved so I recommend you report it so that perhaps in Qt 5.14 or Qt6 it is corrected.

Comment: I already report about this bug -  https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-77798 .  But I have a message  -  "No reviews matched the request. Check your Options in the drop-down menu of this sections header."    I don't understand what means this message.